# How can I place palette items freely, rather than grid based, in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to orient myself with Android Studio (0.3.1) and I'm having trouble placing a button where I want.

When I drag a button from the palette, a grid (3x3 green squares) appears in my frame layout. The button then has to conform to one of these grid "zones".

Can I use x & y to place items rather than this grid? How can I disable the grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AbsoluteLayout see:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your opening layout tag from FrameLayout to RelativeLayout to remove the grid part.